# CSS: Transparent vs. Opacity:0

Tags: css, background-image, opacity, transparent

I wanted to set the entire background of my page to an image. I set the html background with the following code. I noticed the body background was still set to white. I tried 'Opacity:0;' but this made every element in the body 'Opacity:0;' (which was not what I needed). I tried 'background:transparent;" and this seems to work. But I am do not understand the difference between Opacity:0 and Transparent. Can someone explain in layman terms?

```css
@import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);

html{
    background:url('https://stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/22629E3D46.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

body{
    padding-top: 50px;
    background:transparent;
}

.header{
    background-color: white;
}

.body{
}

.box{
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    padding:10px 25px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.popup{
    background-color: blue;
}

.box:hover{
    opacity: .9;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.box-icon{
    background-color:#57a544;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: table;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-61px;
}

.box-icon span{
    color:#fff;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.info h4{
    font-size: 26px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info p{
    color:
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.info a{
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    border:2px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color:#fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.info a:hover{
    background-color: #0288d1;
    box-shadow:0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: #fff;
    transition:all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.2/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/favicon-nav-logo.ico"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Title</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim omnis veritatis quia labore quas eveniet nesciunt dolorum, totam quibusdam aspernatur dignissimos consectetur illum vero, suscipit, beatae accusantium quis perspiciatis natus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

terms?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the background directly to `body`? **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tuyeca/1/edit)**

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

body{
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: url('image.jpg') fixed 50% / cover;
}
```

Opacity is not related to *Background* but to the Element opacity state.
`background: transparent;`  is a transparent background.

Setting an element to `opacity:0;` will make the children "disappear" since the attribute was set to the parent.